# Traveling salesman-like optimization problem - better heuristic required

Tags: optimization, graph-theory, traveling-salesman

I have an optimization problem and I am looking for an algorithm that performs better than the naive method I have.

**The problem**

Consider a graph, `G(N, E)`, where `N` is the set of nodes and `E` is the set of edges. Each node `n_i` in `N` has an associated state `s_i`. I've used a dictionary `D` to store this with nodes as keys and the corresponding state as the value. Adjacent nodes may swap states using a swap manouever. Specifically, a swap manouever is defined as

```
def swap(G, D, n_i, n_j):
    if n_i not in neighbors(G, n_j):
         print('Cannot swap between disconnected nodes')
    else:
         s_i = D[n_i]
         s_j = D[n_j]
         D[n_i] = s_j
         D[n_j] = s_i
    return D
```

Each state must now "visit" a list of other states in a given order, where **visiting means both states must be on any pair of adjacent nodes on `G(N, E)`**. For example `s_1` must visit `[s_3, s_5, s_2]`, `s_2` must visit `[s_1, s_3]`, `s_3` must visit `[s_1, s_2, s_4]` and so on. **The order of visits must be preserved**. However, states are allowed to be on adjacent nodes without marking that as a visit. For instance, if `s_1` starts off adjacent to `s_5`, then it must first become adjacent to `s_3`, mark that visit as done and then become adjacent to `s_5` again. The visitor lists are such that if `s_i` must visit `s_j`, then that also means that `s_j` must visit `s_i` i.e. everything is self-consistent.

**Typical sizes**

The graph is usually around 20-30 nodes, each node is typically connected to 2-4 others. The visit list has no length restriction in principle but in practice doesn't exceed 10.

**The goal**

The goal is to complete the list of visits while minimizing the total number of swap manouvers. What is an efficient algorithm/heuristic for this problem?

**My naive solution**

My current algorithm does the simplest thing one can do. I first see which vists are `(0,0)` visits according to the following function i.e. both states must visit each other before visiting anyone else.

```
def interaction_priority(s1, s2):
    if s2 in visitors_of_s1:
       b = visitors_of_s1.index(s2)
       a = visitors_of_s2.index(s1)
    return (a, b)
```

For these states, I get the current nodes and find the shortest path between those nodes on `G` using a `networx` function. I perform swaps till they are adjacent. Let us assume the previous function returned `(0,0)` for `s_1 and s_3`. Then I find the shortest path between the current nodes of `s_1` and `s_3`

```
inv_D = {s : n for n, s in D.items()} #Invert the dictionary of nodes and states
def get_shortest_path(s1, s3):
    n1 = inv_D[s1]
    n3 = inv_D[s3]
    path_nodes = get_shortest_path(G, n1, n3)
    return path_nodes
```

Now, I perform swaps along this path

```
if len(path_nodes)> 0:
    for i in path_nodes:
         D = swap(G, D, n1, i)

visitors_of_s1.remove(s3)
visitors_of_s3.remove(s1)
```

I'm aware that I can probably optimize things a bit e.g. make the last method symmetric and so on but the fundamental idea is still not very clever. Is there a cleverer algorithm that optimizes how the states move about the graph but still complete all their visits.

Comment: In your naive solution, don't you also need to avoid being adjacent with other states during the sequence of swapping? Sorry if I misunderstood the problem.

Comment: @justhalf, good point - I forgot to add that. You can be adjacent without visiting but to visit, you must be adjacent.

Comment: Can you characterize the size and nature of the datasets?  Specifically, how large are the graphs, what percentage of states have a required visit list, and how long are the visit-lists relative to the total number of states, typically?  Since this may be an O(2^n) or worse problem, it’s very important to know things like this for optimization strategies.

Comment: @RBarryYoung typically around 20-30 nodes, each node is typically connected to 2-4 others. The visit list has no length restriction in principle but in practice under 10.